# How can I get cell formatting when querying via LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, linq-to-excel

I am using LinqPad in conjunction with Linq2Excel to do my own data analysis on an Excel spreadsheet (written and owned by others).  These other people use a lot of cell formatting to represent data.  For example, a grey background cell means "not applicable"; text format == strikethrough means "superceded".

Is there any way to get at these format values in LinqToExcel so I can filter on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to retrieve the cell format values through LinqToExel.

LinqToExcel uses OleDb to retrieve data from the spreadsheets, and OleDb doesn't include information about the cell formatting.